# Classic ASP and Asp dynamic Menu

Tags: html, asp.net

Is there a way to create a dynamic menu that has classic ASP and ASP.net pages without using JavaScript. I tried searching it up and found that I can use HTML5 but I have no clue where to go after. I am also very new to web devlopment and classic ASP and ASP.net and help would be appreciated.

Comment: Javascript just saves you from a page load.  You can create dynamic menus using just ASP or ASP.NET but without javascript it'll be slower.... and I think you'd need to always click some sort of link/button to update anything.  (Just use JS...  whether that's just pure Javascript, jQuery or something like React/Vue/Angular/Blazor)

Comment: You can write IF/THEN logic to decide which HTML to display based on variables.  IF they have this right show them this, otherwise show them this link instead, or do or don't display a graphic, what ever it is.  But you can use ASP to decide which HTML segments to use, and thus dynamically generate the menu, but likely you would also want to use something like a MYSQL database to store those variables.

Comment: Just curious, but did my answer assist you at all, or are you still stuck on this problem?  If it did help can you mark it as the answer, and if it did not help, can you respond with what happened when you tried this technique?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Citation - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

Use the ASP to do If/then blocks to dynamically decide what to display to the user based on the variables you supply.

Example:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
<% if admin = 1 then %>
    <li><a href="admin.asp">Admin</a></li>
<% else %>
    <li><a href="logout.asp">Logout</a></li>
<% end if %>
</ul>
```